# How to easy switch db in Django 1.9.x across multiple servers

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, postgresql

I have one application in Django 1.9.x, and I want to use multidb.

Have any configuration on the settings that I can enter multiple databases, and when it is on a specific server it uses the correct database. For example:

When I'm programming localhost use default, When I put in test serve, automatically switch to testserverdb and when I put in production server use productiondb, I tried use [multi-db documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/) but it's not what I want 'cuze this case is to work with legacy database, not my case.

How I do it?

Comment: Best practice is creating a separate settings.py for each environment. You can have a `base_settings.py` with settings applicable to all environments and then separate `local.py`, `testing.py`, etc. inheriting everything from `base_settings.py` and customizing whatever you need on each environment.

Comment: I read in something about it, i don't remeber where... :), Do you have some examples, like cookbook to do it?

Comment: I read it in Two Scoops of Django, just put in a base module all common settings and then create separate modules for settings that vary depending on your environment. Finally, run `manage.py --settings=path.to.settings`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your settings file:

```
try:
    from [app_name].local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Changes you make in this local_settings file will be overridden. So now you can have a different local_settings file for your localhost, development or production. You can specify a separate db in these files separately.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to have environment specific databases, not necessarily a single app that connects to many databases.  You can easily accomplish this with a custom settings module for each of these environments.

You might have a structure like the following :

```
myproject/
   - settings/
       - __init__.py
       - common.py
```

You'll want to put all your common settings under `common.py`.  This will serve as the basis for all your other environment settings.  From here,there are a few setups that you can use to do what you want, but I'm going to suggest that you use `common.py` as a base settings module that can be overridden locall.y

To do this, you can set your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to by `myproject.settings`, and in your `__init__.py`,

```
from .common import *

try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Then on each environment (production/development/etc), you'll want to include a file named `local.py` in `myproject/settings`.  Any settings you put in that `local.py` file will override your `common.py` when your settings module gets loaded up.